# How can I install different DFS's on IBM Bluemix?

Tags: filesystems, ibm-cloud

As part of my Research Project. I am supposed to test different DFS'S (Distributed File Systems) like HDFS, Ceph etc. For this purpose I have planned to use IBM Bluemix.

I tried doing google to get help in this regard but there is not much available in this regard. Is there any help available in this regard or any suggestion(s) please? Not getting how to start?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you should start using Virtual Machines, get into them and install and test each File System type you want to explore: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/virtualmachines/vm_index.html#vm_index